# Does a mining well retrieve a mob spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

Will a mining well destroy a mob spawner or retrieve it? I am currently driving my mining well through a dungeon i found earlier. If i hit the mob spawner, will it be destroyed or mined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked, mining wells do not pick up mob spawners, however there is a machine in the RotaryCraft mod called the Boring machine, it mines sideways and picks up everything but bedrock, including mob spawners.